# HNibernate: help to avoid N+1 query

Tags: nhibernate

I've got following query

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Income))
                .CreateAlias("Product", "p")
                .SetProjection(
                    Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Product"))
                        .Add(Projections.Sum("Quantity"))
                 );
```

which is translated to sql:

```
SELECT   this_.Product_id    as y0_,
         sum(this_.Quantity) as y1_
FROM     income this_
         inner join products p1_
           on this_.Product_id = p1_.Id
GROUP BY this_.Product_id
```

my domain:

```
class Product
{
    IList<Income> Incomes {get;set;}
}

class Income
{
    Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

when iterating returned collection I have one query for each Product entity.
How can I grab all collection in one query?

Comment: Could you try using the SetFetchMode property? http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/SelectNPlusOne

Comment: already tried - SetFetchMode("p", FetchMode.Join) has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer HQL for that kind of query...

```
select i.Product, sum(i.Quantity)
from Income i
group by /*all product properties*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `Enumerable` instead of `List` to execute the query?